# Using a Join and Component together in Fluent NHibernate Mapping throws "Could not find a getter for property exception"

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Using a Join and Component together in Fluent NHibernate Mapping throws "Could not find a getter for property exception". This is my C# code

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace FnhTest {
    public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer> {
        public CustomerMap() {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Name);

            Join("BillingInfo", m =>
                               {
                                   m.KeyColumn("CustomerId");
                                   m.Component(x => x.BillingInfo, c =>
                                                                   {
                                                                       c.Map(y => y.AccountNumber);
                                                                       c.Map(y => y.Address);
                                                                   });
                               });
        }
    }

    public class BillingInfo {
        public virtual string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual BillingInfo BillingInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my Database structure =>

```
Customers:
  Id (int)
  Name (varchar 50)
BillingInfo:
  Id (int)
  AccountNumber (varchar 50)
  Address (varchar 50)
  CustomerId (int) (Foriegn Key to the Customers Id)
```

Fluent NHibernate generates the right mapping for this setup, but for some reason it throws up an error. Given below are the mapping and the error

`Mapping:`

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="FnhTest.Customer, FnhTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`Customer`">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Name" />
    </property>
    <join table="BillingInfo">
      <key>
        <column name="CustomerId" />
      </key>
      <component name="BillingInfo" insert="true" update="true" optimistic-lock="true">
        <property name="AccountNumber" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <column name="AccountNumber" />
        </property>
        <property name="Address" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <column name="Address" />
        </property>
      </component>
    </join>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`Error:`

```
TestCase 'M:FnhTest.Program.Main(System.String[])'
failed: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

  * Database was not configured through Database method.

    FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

      * Database was not configured through Database method.
     ---> NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for property 'AccountNumber' in class 'FnhTest.Customer'
    at NHibernate.Properties.BasicPropertyAccessor.GetGetter(Type type, String propertyName)
    at NHibernate.Tuple.Component.PocoComponentTuplizer.BuildGetter(Component component, Property prop)
    at NHibernate.Tuple.Component.AbstractComponentTuplizer..ctor(Component component)
    at NHibernate.Tuple.Component.PocoComponentTuplizer..ctor(Component component)
    at NHibernate.Tuple.Component.ComponentEntityModeToTuplizerMapping..ctor(Component component)
    at NHibernate.Tuple.Component.ComponentMetamodel..ctor(Component component)
    at NHibernate.Mapping.Component.BuildType()
    at NHibernate.Mapping.Component.get_Type()
    at NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.IsValid(IMapping mapping)
    at NHibernate.Mapping.PersistentClass.Validate(IMapping mapping)
    at NHibernate.Mapping.RootClass.Validate(IMapping mapping)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Validate()
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
    d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs(93,0): at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    d:\Builds\FluentNH\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs(100,0): at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
    D:\repositories\core\playground\minhajuddin\FnhTest\FnhTest\Program.cs(8,0): at FnhTest.Program.Main(String[] args)

      * Database was not configured through Database method.


0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 6.46 seconds (Ad hoc).
```

I've searched all over the web but was unable to find anything helpful, Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:
Well, I didn't find a way to do this in Fluent NHibernate, I am using whatever Torkel has posted as an answer. But, that was not my intention. Anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BillingInfo looks to me not like a component but an entity.

If you map BillingInfo as an entity you can map it from Customer as a  association.

```
<many-to-one name="BillingInfo" property-ref="CustomerId" cascade="none"/>
```

The property-ref is importand as you do not want to join on on the BillingInfo Id but on the CustomerId, this however requires you to add a CustomerId property to your BillingInfo class.

Comment: Yeah this can be done, But I would always need a `BillingInfo` object when I have a customer, I know this can be done with a `one to one` mapping but I prefer this way, because it automatically does an `outer join` in this case

Comment: Well it isn't going to work unless you design it properly. Torkel's advice is sound.

Comment: I agree with whatever Torkel is saying, but I was just wondering why it's not possible in Fluent NHibernate, when it is possible to do the same in NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this is a dumb observation, but don't you need an Id member in BillingInfo?

Comment: I do have an Id field in my BillingInfo class, but it's kind of redundant, because it's not populated by NHibernate